# hide td with jquery based on its contents

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

i need to hide a TD which contains the contents "Email Address". This is because its generated via the code and i dont have the source code.

Below is the generated code:

```
<div id="ptkSubscribe">
        <table width="50px" style="width:50px" class="NewsletterBox">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>

<input type="hidden" value="" id="txt_NL_FirstName">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="txt_NL_LastName">

        <tr>
        <td>Email Address</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="13" onkeypress="enterSubmit(event);" id="txtEmailAddress"><br>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="txtCaptcha"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="2"><input type="button" onclick="clickSubmit();" id="cmdSubmit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has a `:contains` selector which will select elements if they contain text.  It's likely a lot slower than regular selectors, so you'll want to specify a target region (the table) to make it a bit more efficient.

Something along the lines of this should work...

`$('td:contains(Email Address)', '#ptkSubscribe').hide();`

[:contains reference](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: I cant just hide the class ptkSubscribe as that contains the textbox and submit button for the newsletter. I just want to hide the label which is code generated.

Comment: edit: sorry it works, but i am usuing dotnetstorefront and appears the jquery wont fire..